# Regex .NET Trying to capture group with lookahead that repeat

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

***Please note that i'm using the .NET regex engine here***

**Here is the parsing string :**

```
    <div class="c411Listing" onmouseover="ResidentialListings.enhanceListing(this, 1);" onmouseout="ResidentialListings.degradeListing(this, 1);">

    <div id="Contact1" class="listingDetail">

        <span id="ContactName1" class="c411ListedName"><a href="/res/5068300124/P-DESCHESNES/184421926.html" onclick="utagsave();" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'person_name', link_attr1:'in_listing'})" title="P DESCHESNES  on 85 Red Pine Dr">P DESCHESNES</a></span>

        <span class="c411Phone" id="ContactPhone1">(506) 830-2224</span>

        <span class="c411ListingGeo"><span class="adr" id="ContactAddress1">85 Fictive Dr NB</span></span>


        <a class="c411GetDirections c411NoPrint" id="ContactDirections1" href="/map/mapSearch.html?layers=dir&amp;from=85+Red+Pine+Dr+NB&amp;what=P+Deschesnes&amp;where=Canada" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'direction', link_attr1:'in_listing'});" rel="nofollow">Get directions&nbsp;<span>&rarr;</span></a>


    </div>
    <div class="c411HoverMarker c411NoPrint" style="display:none;">
        <a href="/res/5068300124/P-DESCHESNES/184421926.html" title="P DESCHESNES"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="c411Listing" onmouseover="ResidentialListings.enhanceListing(this, 2, 0);" onmouseout="ResidentialListings.degradeListing(this, 2, 0);">

    <div id="Contact2" class="listingDetail">

        <span id="ContactName2" class="c411ListedName"><a href="/res/4189883202/P-Deschesnes/179906536.html" onclick="utagsave();" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'person_name', link_attr1:'in_listing'})" title="P Deschesnes  on 6585 Rue des Orchid&eacute;es">P Deschesnes</a></span>

        <span class="c411Phone" id="ContactPhone2">(418) 987-3202</span>

        <span class="c411ListingGeo"><span class="adr" id="ContactAddress2">1000 Rue des Fictive QC G1X 3Z5</span></span>


        <a class="c411GetDirections c411NoPrint" id="ContactDirections2" href="/map/mapSearch.html?layers=dir&amp;from=1000+Rue+des+Orchid%C3%A9esFictive+QC+G1X+3Z5&amp;what=P+Deschesnes&amp;where=Canada" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'direction', link_attr1:'in_listing'});" rel="nofollow">Get directions&nbsp;<span>&rarr;</span></a>


    </div>
    <div class="c411HoverMarker c411NoPrint" style="display:none;">
        <a href="/res/4189883202/P-Deschesnes/179906536.html" title="P Deschesnes"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="c411Listing" onmouseover="ResidentialListings.enhanceListing(this, 3, 0);" onmouseout="ResidentialListings.degradeListing(this, 3, 0);">

    <div id="Contact3" class="listingDetail">

        <span id="ContactName3" class="c411ListedName"><a href="/res/4506702257/P-DESCHESNES/181606171.html" onclick="utagsave();" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'person_name', link_attr1:'in_listing'})" title="P DESCHESNES  on 1736 Rue Saint-Alexandre">P DESCHESNES</a></span>

        <span class="c411Phone" id="ContactPhone3">(450) 671-1111</span>

        <span class="c411ListingGeo"><span class="adr" id="ContactAddress3">1736 Rue Fictive Longueuil QC J1J 1T2</span></span>


        <a class="c411GetDirections c411NoPrint" id="ContactDirections3" href="/map/mapSearch.html?layers=dir&amp;from=1000+Rue+Saint-Fictive+Longueuil+QC+J1J+1T1&amp;what=P+Deschesnes&amp;where=Canada" onmousedown="utag.link({link_name:'direction', link_attr1:'in_listing'});" rel="nofollow">Get directions&nbsp;<span>&rarr;</span></a>


    </div>
    <div class="c411HoverMarker c411NoPrint" style="display:none;">
        <a href="/res/4506702257/P-DESCHESNES/181606171.html" title="P DESCHESNES"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the repeating pattern here. I would like to get a match for each Contact(1,2,3)  with 3 groups inside : ContactName,Phone and address.

For this example i should get 3 matchs each containing the name,phone and address,but for some reasons i only get the last phone and address.

Here my .NET regex so far :

```
(?si)(?(?=.*<div id="Contact[\d{1,2}]").*<span id="ContactName[\d{1,2}]\".*title=.*>(.*)</a>.*id="ContactPhone[\d{1,2}]">(.*)</span>.*id="ContactAddress[\d{1,2}]\">(.*)</span>)
```

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

For very simple fragments of HTML, regexes can be useful. For something more extensive, like your example, an HTML parser like the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) would probably be the most robust solution.

There are reasons to not try parsing HTML with regexes: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) .

Comment: I understand this and i will look further to it, but can you please help me find the solution above with the reg ex and example. It will help me understand .net reg ex in this case

Comment: It's *possible* that you need to use a non-greedy modifier for your `.*`s: `.*?`.